# CFGs and Pushdown Automata

Tags: pushdown-automata

Is this the CFG for part (a),

```
                         S -> AxxyxxA
                         A -> Ax|ε
```

If this is the answer then this grammar would accept "xxyxxx" also which is wrong. How to do it if this is wrong?

[image]

Comment: We require you to credit the original source of the material that you have copied (that is currently in an image): https://cs.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Don't use images as main content of your post. This makes your question impossible to search and inaccessible to the visually impaired; [we don't like that](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/752/should-we-do-anything-about-questions-that-are-just-a-scan-of-a-problem-in-their). Please transcribe text and mathematics.  You can [use LaTeX](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands).

Comment: Please note that 'CFGs and Pushdown Automata' is not a question. Can you state the question in the title?

Answer (score 0):

As you noticed, the CFG you have given accepts words not in the language $L$. Therefore, no, it is not correct. We will not do your homework for you, but I will give you the hint that your current CFG is looking at the language "inside-out".